# Axios interceptor async call to get token throws error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, auth0

After the user log into my application using Auth0, I'm getting other user settings from another api, however, this call does not seem to work, in fact it doesn't seem to like me adding the access_token from auth0.

I always end up with an error of: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

The code that is called after login in:

```
export default observer(function LoginMenu() {
const { currentUserStore: { login }} = useStore();
const { loginWithRedirect, isAuthenticated, logout } = useAuth0();

useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
        login()
    }
  }, [isAuthenticated])
  
  const handleLogin = async () => {
    await loginWithRedirect({
        prompt: "login",
        appState: {
            returnTo: "/callback",
        },
    });
  }
  
  ....
  })
```

Login function:

```
login = async () => {
    this.loading = true;
    try {
        console.log("Calling API to get currentUser");
        var user = await agent.CurrentUserApi.get();

        console.log("currentUser: ", user);
    } catch(error) {
        runInAction(() => this.loading = false);
        throw error;
    }
}
```

Agent interceptor:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(config => {
const { getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0();

config.headers = config.headers ?? {};
const token = getAccessTokenSilently();
if (token) {
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`
}
return config;
})
```

From everything I can see, the issue is related to how the interceptor is working, without the interceptor the api call is made, however, without a access token, so the call fails to authenticate.

Comment: You can't use books outside of a component's body

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71558686/3760754) to pass `getAccessTokenSilently()` to your axios config code.